# Create a query to loop through when there are no matching condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table  with following rows.

table1:

```
id  col1   col2  date
1   ttx   123    13-05-2020 
2   abc   436    13-05-2020 
1   ccy   879    13-05-2020
```

below is the main table which has historical records.

table2:

```
date        col1  col3  col4
13-05-2020   xyz   ttx  1
13-05-2020   xyz   abc  2
13-05-2020   xyz   ccy  3
--------
13-05-2019   xyz   ttx  1
13-05-2019   xyz   abc  2
13-05-2019   xyz   ccy  3
```

---

`col1` of table 1 and `col3` of table 2 have similar data.

I have to calculate average for all ids like : 
to get value for matched date and previous year date like for `Id=1` , below `col4` will be picked.

```
date        col1  col3  col4
13-05-2020   xyz   ttx  1
13-05-2019   xyz   ttx  1
```

**average 1+1/2=1**

expected output:

```
id  col1   col2  date          average
1   xyz   123    13-05-2020    1
2   abc   436    13-05-2020    2
1   ccy   879    13-05-2020    3
```

I am trying with joining table but not sure how to select previous year date:

```
SELECT id, col1, col2, date
    , t2.col4 + /2 As 'average'
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 on t1.date = t2.date
```

Any idea how to start/go ahead to get expected output?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @DaleK .. Actually i am looking for hints so that i can start creating a query .I am clueless where to start.

Comment: @Harsh . . . I can't figure out what you are trying to do.  You have one result set with two rows and one with three rows.  Mostly it looks like  a `join` is sufficient.  I just don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding, but I think it would be better to JOIN on id, or whichever value you want to calculate the average over, and then use a GROUP BY on the date column. Then you could use the AVG function to let SQL do the work of calculating the averages.

Some documenation on calculation the average: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you the desired output:

```
SELECT MAX(T1.ID) as ID, MAX(T1.Col1) as Col1, 
MAX(T1.Col2) as Col2, MAX(T1.[date]) as date,
AVG(T2.Col4) as [average]
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col3
GROUP BY T1.Col1
```

Comment: it will not work as we have to get average for each and every record of table 1 ,even if ids are duplicate.