# Create a function to to get the average in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table  with following rows

table 1:

```
id  col1   col2  date
1   ttx   123    13-05-2020 
2   abc   436    13-05-2020 
1   ccy   879    13-05-2020
```

below is the main table which has historical records.

table 2

```
date        col1  col3  col4
13-05-2020   xyz   ttx  1
13-05-2020   xyz   abc  2
13-05-2020   xyz   ccy  3
--------
13-05-2019   xyz   ttx  1
13-05-2019   xyz   abc  2
13-05-2019   xyz   ccy  3

------
```

`col1` of table 1 and `col3` of table 2 have similar data.

Expected output:

```
id  col1   col2  date          average
1   xyz   123    13-05-2020    1
```

I am creating a function which will take a `col1` and `date` as an input  and return the average value.

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].fn_GetData
    (
      @date DATE ,
      @col1 VARCHAR(10)
    )
RETURNS INT
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @result INT;    
        DECLARE @previousdate DATE;
        SET @previousdate = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CAST(@date AS DATE));

        WITH    cte1
                  AS ( SELECT   *
                       FROM     table2
                       WHERE    date = @date
                                AND col3 = @col1
                       UNION
                       SELECT   *
                       FROM     table2
                       WHERE    date = @previousdate
                                AND col3 = @col1
                     )
            SELECT  @result = 1 / AVG(cte1.col4)
            FROM    cte1; 

        RETURN @result;
    END;
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Define better? If your current function works what actually is your question?

Comment: Don't `SELECT   *` would be an improve in all queries, select the specific columns you want.

Comment: I don't know what `rate` is, but it appears to be a numeric datatype, so why is `@result` a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: I answered you the query for finding average to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61769476/create-a-query-to-loop-through-when-there-are-no-matching-condition-in-sql/61778903#61778903

Comment: @HoneyBadger ,i have corrected it .

Comment: @DaleK .. Yes,I have tried provided answers but it didnt work.

Comment: @Harsh if the answers given don't fully answer your question, then please leave comments explaining why not so that the people providing the answers have a chance to give you a better answer.

Comment: Would better also mean that fn_GetData('2020-05-13', 'abc') should return 0.5 instead of 0?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning it will return 2 in above case but yes if there any decimal comes out of average it should return decimal value.

Comment: Maybe you haven't pasted the code you're actually using. `1 / AVG(cte1.col4)` returns 0.5, not 2, but because you're using `int` it gets truncated to 0.

Comment: @DaleK . . . .There is no issue at all with `select *` in subqueries and CTEs -- at least in most databases and SQL Server has a good optimizer.

Comment: @Harsh . . . I can't figure out how the desired results relate to the data you have provided.  You need to be clearer about the operations you want to perform.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sure from a performance perspective, but its a good habit in general to list the required columns for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont need in many places, you dont need function for calculating average. you can use below query to get average.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.col1,ot.col4_avg as [average]
FROM table1 AS t1
CROSS APPLY 
(
SELECT Avg(CAST(col4 AS DECIMAL(14,2))) as col4_avg
FROM table2 as t2
WHERE t2.date = t1.date and t2.col3 = t1.col1
) as ot(col4_avg)
```